# Why is the insulator missing for one of the transmission lines?

Tags: transmission, line, isolator

Why is the insulator missing for one of the transmission lines? Apart from the top line (earth) I would assume that all the other lines need an insulator.

It's the same for the next poles. This is in Switzerland.

[image: Dead end tower in Switzerland]

Comment: what about the next power pole?

Comment: The isolator is there; it's just missing the surrounding ceramic insulator. Probably will be replaced in due course.

Comment: Maybe the insulator got hit by lightning or broke? Look for shards on the ground

Answer (score 1):

The loop under is also not as generous as for the other conductors. The line cannot be used in that state because snow and ice could start accumulating on it. I'm guessing that there is a rule that the mechanical load has to be balanced, that is they cannot simply omit a conductor if, on the opposite side of the pole arm, there is a conductor. That to prevent a twisting effect on the pole.
There is an interesting article here on the power systems used in various railways including Switzerland. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_kV_AC_railway_electrification

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that one system on the pole is a railway powerline.
Therefore the cable with the missing insulator must be a spare one.

Comment: What is a "train transmission network"?

Comment: i changed it to railway powerline

Comment: That seems unlikely. Without insulators it can't quickly be put into service. Also there doesn't seem to be any suggestion of railway in the question or photo and the Armco-style barrier (although there are two strange signs with white rectangle in black diamond). If it is a railway is isn't using overhead electrification. It looks more like dual three-phase transmission so I'm interested in seeing what answers come up.